# Why are if statements preferred over switch statements?

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to programming from scratch but have experience reading and fixing code. Going through actual classes and learning I have noticed that there is more implementation on IF statements than Switch statements. What is the difference and why are the learning materials always wanting if statements?

I have looked at a few different articles around stackoverflow but they are for specific problems, this is more of the big picture when writing a script from scratch.

Comment: I think its just more popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**if statements**

- Allow for more than one piece of state to be checked which is often necessary.
- Allow for a single boolean value to be checked in much less code  than a switch statement
- Offer logic that is easier to follow in general and especially when nested than switches

**switch statements**

- Allow for easy checking of one piece of state with multiple possible variations. It is most useful when there are 3+ possible states.
- Allow for easy additions and handling of new possible states. This is useful for future extensions of an application. For instance, if an API may include more routes in the future.
- Allow for easy grouping of states that will handle the same way or very closely. This is also very clear and easy to adjust.

---

They both have their merits, but the use of **switch statements** is more niche when something like **if** is available.

As a Developer you pick the right tool for the job, and if something is more or just as performant, more or just as legible, and allows for less code, that is what will often be used.

It's also worth noting that there are situations where you may use an if statement within a switch. There's nothing saying you have to use one or the other - It's all based upon **organization, code readability, and practicality**.

---

*As a side note since you brought up coursework...*

Look, being in a development course and being in the field are vastly different animals. I have personally seen awful collegiate courses that literally teach aspiring Developers nothing more than the **if...else if...else** control statements. I've seen a recent graduate code **literally** ( and I do mean literally ) dozens of these statements when a simple Array check would've sufficed and would've saved time, over a hundred lines of code, and the sanity of everyone else on the project ( namely me ).

School is school. You do the work how they want, even if it's not really the most practical or efficient, but when you enter the field keep in mind that there are often better ways.

I only mention this because it's likely you may have seen something that made you say "*but why wouldn't I just do X?*". I'm here to tell you, you may be right, so keep your head up. Research it on your own and feel free to ask those who have more experience. **Curiosity** is the mark of a good Developer and you'll be much more capable and valuable when you get into the field.

Answer (score 0):

Programming constructs like if and switch have their strengths. we use if mostly in many languages over if. But  for multiple condition checking switch is a lot easier to choose.

Answer (score 0):

Because it (`if`) sounds better if you think about logic.

```
if(life_is_easy){
  just_sleep_you_will_succeed()
}else{
  struggle_for_success()
}
```

Switch is however preferred if you have long journey of variable testing.
You may notice that, above sentence also contains IF to form logical consultation.